# keep users logged in using Knox Token Authentication django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am having a hard time trying to figure this out.

I am trying to use the django rest api knox token authentication and React.

This is what my code looks like in Authenticate.js

```js
export function LoginComponent (props) {
    const [state, setState] = useState({credentials : {username: '',password: '',}})   
    const [hasLoggedIn, setHasLoggedIn] = useState(false) 
    const Login = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/accounts/api/auth/login",{
        method: "POST", 
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify(state.credentials)
        })
        .then( data => data.json()).then(
            data => {
                console.log(data.token)
                props.userLogin(data.token)
            }
        )
        .then(
            console.log(hasLoggedIn),
            setHasLoggedIn(true),
            props.LoggedIn(hasLoggedIn))
        .catch(error => console.error())
      }
    const Register = (event) => {
        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/accounts/api/auth/register",{
        method: "POST", 
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify(state.credentials)
        }).then( data => data.json()).then(
            data => {
                console.log(data.token)
            }
        ).catch(error => console.error())
    }
    const inputChanged = (event) =>{
        const cred = state.credentials;
        cred[event.target.name] = event.target.value
        setState({credentials: cred})
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <label>
                Username:
                <input type='text' name='username'
                value={state.credentials.username} 
                onChange={inputChanged}
                />
            </label>
            <br/>
            <label>
                Password:
                <input type='password' name='password'
                value={state.credentials.password} 
                onChange={inputChanged}
                />
            </label>
            <br/>
            <button onClick={Login}>Login</button>
            <button onClick={Register}>Register</button>
        </div>
        )
}
```

This is a code I made from a youtube video
The problem comes while trying to keep the users authenticated, if you refresh on this current code, you will end up losing the Token, which means you have to login again.

Is there anyway I can use the Django session authentication with the tokens?

Any help would be appriciated. Thanks in Advance!

**EDIT**
This is my Login API view.

```
class LoginApi(generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny, 
    ]
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data
        login(request, user)
        _, token = AuthToken.objects.create(user)
        return Response({
        "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
        "token": token
        })
```

**This is my Serializer Class**

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  username = serializers.CharField()
  password = serializers.CharField()
  class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "password"]

  def validate(self, data):
    user = authenticate(**data)
    if user and user.is_active:
      return user
    raise serializers.ValidationError("Incorrect Credentials")
```

Comment: Show your backend code - login view

Comment: @monio 
```class LoginApi(generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny, 
    ]
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data
        login(request, user)
        _, token = AuthToken.objects.create(user)
        return Response({
        "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
        "token": token
        }) ```

Comment: Check one thing for me please, login on chrome tab and login on chrome PRIVATE tab - did you logged out from first tab ? (you need to make second login in private tab to make sure cookies are not shared).

Comment: @monio it doesn't keep me logged in on the private tab if you're referring to that

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you only save the token in the client (web browser) memory. on every refresh the memory is "cleaned".
As I see it you have two options:

1. Save the token in [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)
2. Use a different method of authentication that involves cookies, preferably [http-cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)